# Custom Filter in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.7.4. I would like to show in filter only countries used in foreign field of CarMake model. I have tried two variants but it does not work. If I put simply 'country' in list_filter it shows all countries.  What am I doing wrong?

#model.py

```
from apps.location.models import Country

class CarMake(BaseModel):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       country = models.ForeignKey(Country, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## admin.py

```
from . import models
class CarMakeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = models.CarMake
    list_display = ('name', 'country')
    list_filter = (
        #(CountryFilter), -> Variant I
        ('country', 'RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter'), #Variant II
    )
```

Variant I

```
class CountryFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('by country')
    parameter_name = 'country'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        countries = set([c.country for c in model_admin.model.objects.all()])
        return [(c.id, c.name) for c in countries]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(country__id__exact=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```

Variant II

```
class RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter(admin.RelatedFieldListFilter):
    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        self.request = request
        self.model_admin = model_admin
        super(RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter, self).__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)

    def choices(self, cl):
        limit_choices_to = set(self.model_admin.queryset(self.request).values_list(self.field.name, flat=True))
        self.lookup_choices = [(pk_val, val) for pk_val, val in self.lookup_choices if pk_val in limit_choices_to]
        return super(RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter, self).choices(cl)
```

Comment: In the documentation they return a tuple in `lookups()` and not a list

Comment: What happens with Variant1 that code looks fine to me. Is there an error or is it that all the countries are listed. Can you retry with that and post the outcome? (that query is a bit expensive but it can be easily rectified)

Comment: Variant I does not filter out distinct values, but shows all countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem.

```
class CountryFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Country')
    parameter_name = 'country'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        countries = []
        qs = Country.objects.filter(id__in = model_admin.model.objects.all().values_list('country_id', flat = True).distinct())
        for c in qs:
            countries.append([c.id, c.name])
        return countries

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(country__id__exact=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```